# vector of vector having reverse same numbers

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a vector of vector let's call it:

```
vector<vector<int> > data;
```

and in data it has numbers like

```
0 1
0 3
0 4
1 0
1 2
1 5
3 0
```

how could I get rid of the data that is a reverse of itself? For example: 0 1 and 1 0 and I would like to get rid of 1 0 because I already saw 0 1. Another example: 0 3 and 3 0 and I would like to get rid of 3 0 because I already saw 0 3.

So the data would instead be this:

```
0 1
0 3
0 4
1 2
1 5
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Do you have to use a vector? Does the result have to be sorted?

Comment: I do not have to use a vector and yes the data has to be sorted

Comment: Do you always get 2 numbers per line, or can there be more?

Comment: Always 2 per line. for the data I have two for loops where the two ints that I get the data from are int i and int j

Comment: Is your data actually restricted to small integers like this?  What is the real range of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the vectors in a set and check if the reverse is already in the set. Something like this:

C++11 version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

vector<int> myrev(vector<int>& f)
{
  vector<int> s;
  s.push_back(f[1]);
  s.push_back(f[0]);
  return s;
}
int main()
{
  vector<vector<int> > data={{0,1},{0,3},{0,4},{1,0},{1,2},{1,5},{3,0},{1,0}};
  set<vector<int> > unique_data;
  for(auto& x: data)
  {
    if(unique_data.find(myrev(x))==unique_data.end())
      unique_data.insert(x);
  }
  for(auto& x: unique_data)
  {
    cout << x[0] << ":" << x[1] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

C++98 version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

vector<int> myrev(vector<int>& f)
{
  vector<int> s;
  s.push_back(f[1]);
  s.push_back(f[0]);
  return s;
}
int main()
{
  vector<vector<int> > data;
  //lame C++98 initialization of the vector
  vector<int> tmp(2);
  tmp[0]=0;tmp[1]=1;
  data.push_back(tmp);
  tmp[0]=0;tmp[1]=3;
  data.push_back(tmp);
  tmp[0]=0;tmp[1]=4;
  data.push_back(tmp);
  tmp[0]=1;tmp[1]=0;
  data.push_back(tmp);
  tmp[0]=1;tmp[1]=2;
  data.push_back(tmp);
  tmp[0]=1;tmp[1]=5;
  data.push_back(tmp);
  tmp[0]=3;tmp[1]=0;
  data.push_back(tmp);

  set<vector<int> > unique_data;
  for(vector<vector<int> >::iterator x=data.begin(); x!=data.end(); x++)
  {
    if(unique_data.find(myrev(*x))==unique_data.end())
      unique_data.insert(*x);
  }
  for(set<vector<int> >::iterator x=unique_data.begin(); x!=unique_data.end(); x++)
  {
    cout << (*x)[0] << ":" << (*x)[1] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's probably because the code was in C++11 and you are using C++98. I wrote a C++98 version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably want to print out the values without their opposites, you could do this:

```
for each pair:
    if it exists in the HashMap:
       do nothing
    else
        add the opposite to a HashMap 
        print the pair
```

Comment: Could you give an example of this in code? I'm not too familiar with Hashmaps.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to use a lot of memory, and the maximum size of the integers is small like in your example, I would simply create a bit-vector big enough to hold the entire search space.  Compute an index into this bit vector from both input numbers.

```
int N_POSSIBLE_PAIRS = (1 << MAX_BITS) * (1 << MAX_BITS);

// vector<bool> is specialized - it only uses 1 bit per entry
std::vector<bool> bitset(N_POSSIBLE_PAIRS);

int index = (first << MAX_BITS) | second;

// in a loop,
if (bitset[index]) {
    // duplicate
}
else {
    int reverse_index = (second << MAX_BITS) | first;
    bitset[index] = true;
    bitset[reverse_index] = true;
}
```

This actually wastes 2x space - you could fix that with a more complex indexing scheme if necessary.

If the maximum size of the integers is too big, or you are restricted in memory, *or you just prefer to be frugal with memory,* then I would sort the pairs lexicographically and use binary search to check for duplicates.

It's also possible that my suggestion will perform poorly on sparse data because it is not cache-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming there are no negative numbers in your list, and for space reasons, the numbers are not too large):

1) Create a bitset 2d grid with size MxM (where M is the maximum number to expect).  Set each bit in the grid to 0

2) For each pair of numbers (x,y):

```
check if grid(x,y) is 1.  If yes then you have a duplicate
else
check if grid(y,x) is 1.  If yes then you have a duplicate.
set grid(x,y) and grid(y,x) to 1
```

Comment: But then (0, 2) and (1, 0) will make it seem like (0, 0) has been seen.

Comment: Changed the algo to use a grid of bits. Probably still not the best, but it more than likely works. Looks like your answer though, so you beat me to it.  Give you a +1.